# Add a button or image button that calls wp functions in the wp-admin

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, uploads

I have a custom post type of products that I've setup to upload PDF's using metaboxes.  When I generate the metaboxes on the wp-admin, I look to see if the metabox already has a pdf uploaded to it or not.  If it DOES I generate a link to the pdf.  If it doesn't I generate a file upload control where they can pick a file to upload if they want.  Here's what my function looks like that generates this metadata.

```
function products_pdf_uploads_show_meta() {
    global $meta_box_pdf_uploads, $post, $prefix;

    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    echo '<p class="description">Upload your PDFs here </p>';
    foreach ($meta_box_pdf_uploads['fields'] as $field) {       

        //Get current PDF meta
        $pdf_array = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        //Grab the filename from the end of the path
        $pdf_filename = substr(strrchr($pdf_array['url'], "/"), 1);

        echo '<tr>',
                '<td>';                     
                    //If Empty, show file upload dialog
                    if(empty($pdf_array)) { 
                        echo '<input type="file" style="width: 700px;" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" />';

                    } else {  //Else if pdf exists, show link to pdf and add DELETE button
                        echo '<li><a href="' . $pdf_array['url'] . '" target=_blank">'. $pdf_filename . '</a></li>';
                    }

        echo    '</td>',
             '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

What I'd like to do is if there is a PDF metadata (meaning there's a pdf already uploaded), I'd like to put a DELETE button next to the PDF Link.

```
 } else {  //Else if pdf exists, show link to pdf and add DELETE button
      echo '<li><a href="' . $pdf_array['url'] . '" target=_blank">'. $pdf_filename . '</a></li>' ;
      //I Want to add a delete button after the above echo
     }
```

The delete button will remove all metadata from the PRODUCT post type, and delete the file off the server.  SO I guess my question is how can I make a button that hooks into wordpress functions such as `delete_post_meta` ?  I'm using `wp_upload_bits()` to upload the pdf's mostly because I don't want the PDF's added to the media library, just want to upload them to the server and get a path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for Ajax.
This Q&A may give you an idea: [Unattaching images from a post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54822/12615).

There are many specialists on the matter here at WPSE, check this [search query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwp-admin%5D+ajax).

Comment: Ahh I think I see. But instead of UNATTACHING my function would remove the metadata and delete the files right?

Comment: Yep, the `wpse_54822_unattach` PHP function is called by the Javascript. Execute what you need there, and you can also give a response back with a value.

Comment: Thank you! I will research this.  Definitely a step in the right direction. THANK YOU!

Comment: All of that is sort of overwhelming. I'm assuming since I've already created my DELETE button (that I can give a class or ID for jquery to reference) the only thing I need to do is create my function that runs the `delete_post_meta` and deletes the files right? And then write the jquery code to fire the function?

Comment: I think you should open a new Question, with your new working code. Because this one was about on how to execute a PHP function dispatched by an `onClick` event. And by now you probably have a completely different code. I'd also suggest that you publish it in full, or at least with all working relevant parts.

Comment: Actually my code hasn't changed at all. But after researching what you posted, I think I know what to do:  create a function that deletes meta data and the pdf off the server, and write the jquery to execute that function when the DELETE button is clicked.  Does that sound about right?  THANK YOU!

Comment: How does it comes that it didn't change? I suppose now you have `add_action( 'wp_ajax_...`, no? Anyway, yes, the button click should call the `wp_ajax` action and do it's work. Don't you have a testing server installed in your machine? If not, it's definitely a must :P

Comment: Oh of course I'm testing everything first before uploading to production.  Site isn't even technically up yet.  I haven't written any code yet to start this because I'm reading up on everything and trying to understand it.  Thanks for all your help. I'm about to start coding tonight.

Comment: I'm going to give you the answer on this quesiton since you've gotten me farther than I ever could have on my own, but I'll start a new question with updated code.  THANK YOU!